# Obscure Azure Data Factory Error on Snowflake Lookup Activity - The remote name could not be resolved: transfereu2storage1.blob.core.windows.net

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

Over the last few days we have occasionally see our Snowflake lookup activities failing due to the error "The remote name could not be resolved: transfereu2storage1.blob.core.windows.net". Rerunning the activity results in a success.

What's very strange is I check our Snowflake query history and see that the task ran successfully, so I imagine transferring the data back to Azure Data Factory is where the task fails out. There doesn't seem to be any pattern to these errors as it will randomly happen across any of our lookup activities. It will usually happen to 1-3 lookup activities out of 100 or so. Has anyone seen this error?

[image: Task Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

It might be a transient issue. As you mentioned rerunning results in success, you can try utilizing **`Retry`** (provide the number of retry attempts) and **`Retry interval`** (the duration between each Retry attempt) in `lookup activity` under General.

[image]

Comment: At this point I think we will reach out to Azure support and see if something failed on the backend. I'm not opposed to using retries but really want to hear what happened and see if theres something architecturally wrong with our Data Factory design. Thanks for your suggestion!